# Scrolling past top with fixed navbar behaving differently across different browsers

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm encountering an issue with a fixed navbar in [twitter-bootstrap-3](/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap-3) that I can't quite find an explanation or solution for.

When I scroll past the top of the page there is different behaviour in different browsers:

In Chrome (MacOS), the whole content scrolls down, like this:

[image]

In Safari (also Mac), the navbar stays fixed on top, and the background appears below it:

[image]

Ideally, I would prefer the behaviour as it is in Chrome. I have tried numerous approaches with [css](/questions/tagged/css) using `overflow`, `position`, but I can't figure it out. Can I correct this behaviour with CSS (or perhaps Javascript/jQuery?)

Here's the bare bones of my code (the `!important`s are just here to override Bootstrap styling):

```css
body {
    background-color: #eee !important;
    padding-top: 54px !important;
}

.navbar {
    min-height: 54px !important;
    border-bottom: 2px solid orange !important;
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}

.navbar-default {
    background: #fff !important;
    .navbar-brand {
        color: #000 !important;
    }
}

.usp-bar {
    background-color: orange;
    color: #fff;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
}

.content {
  height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<body>

  <div id="app">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    Navbar
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="usp-bar">
      orange bar
    </div>

    <div class="content">
      Content
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hacks**

See puresamari's gist "[overscroll background-color on ios](https://gist.github.com/puresamari/037f486166953b5a7b95d96ad925e645)" that places a `fixed` container in the negative space above the page. Doesn't work in Safari 11 or mobile Safari.

**Overscroll-Behavior**

Chrome 63 introduced the [`overscroll-behavior`](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/11/overscroll-behavior) property that lets you disable scroll chaining or overscrolling altogether. However, still not supported in Safari ☹

**Final Advice**

The most reliable method is setting a background color on `html` and another on `body`, i.e. http://peter.coffee/htmls-background-color.

It's not yet possible to control how browsers overscroll, so instead set the correct colors and leave negative space at the top of the page for the fixed header.

Interestingly that's what StackOverflow does:

```
.top-bar {
    height: 50px;
}

.top-bar._fixed {
    position: fixed;
    min-width: auto;
}

.top-bar ~ .container, .top-bar ~ #announcement-banner {
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Comment: So 'overscroll' is the word I was looking for :). Interesting knowledge, apparently it doesn't solve my problem (completely), but I've got something to work with. Thanks!